# Drupal + Nutch + Solr

Tags: drupal, solr, nutch

We're about to start a project consisting of a search engine website. We need to implement a site that has social functionalities upon it's core search engine solution. Obviously, we need to choose a good web crawler along with a full text search engine. Since our team have good experience developing websites with Drupal; a member of the team came up with this solution: integrating Drupal social functionalities with Nutch as a web crawler and Solr as the FTS search engine.

First question: What do you think of our choice? Is there a way to make Nutch and Solr work seamlessly within Drupal?

Second one: Is there any way some good crawling/indexing/searching solutions that merge well with Drupal?

Third question: (as suggested by a member of the team) What about coding the entire site with a UI Java framework like Wicket and integrate it with Nutch and Solr since all three technologies are Java based?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This video can be a starting point for you. http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/how-build-jobs-aggregation-search-engine-nutch-apache-solr-and-views-3-about.html

Also the module is live now and you can access it here http://drupal.org/project/nutch.

Answer (score 0):

I and some others are working on this and have bespoke solutions ready for use.

First, please join the discussion on groups.drupal.org: http://groups.drupal.org/lucene-nutch-and-solr
Then, check out the nutch module for Drupal: drupal.org/project/nutch

Finally, if you need to have it work with with multiple languages or in a multi-site environment, you'll need code that I've written and that will eventually be released as part of the drupal.org nutch project, but which isn't there yet. Watch the issue queue or contact me directly to get your hands on it.

-Robert